# How can I make Xerox Phaser 3020's drivers work in Debian 8, Jessie?

Tags: debian, drivers, printer

I own a Xerox Phaser 3020 printer wich I want to use from a computer running on Debian 8, Jessie. The drivers available at [Xerox's web site](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-3020/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux) support Debian 5.0 - 7.1. So they explicitly state that there is no Debian 8 support.

I've tried installing the drivers anyway. Not surprisingly they don't work regardless of the way I connect to the printer (USB or LAN). **Is there a way I can bypass this restriction and make the drivers that work on Debian7.1 work on Debian8?**

Alternatively I can access via IP the printer's Centreware Internet Services page. There I can load a 'print-ready file' (extension .prn) for the printer to print. How can I generate this file without the drivers installed?

Comment: Given that this printer is a "PostScript Printer" there should be no problem. In fact, the [drivers recomended here](https://www.openprinting.org/driver/Postscript-Xerox/) are almost generic and is only a PPD file for CUPS. Just follow the steps given in the above link. ...... Or: ... Are you trying to get the printer working with some other server different from CUPS?

Comment: CUPS alone didn't come with the drivers or could't find them. That's why I tried to install the drivers manually.
I just solved it. The drivers were correctly installed, but I had to re-add the printer in CUPS, then it found the installed drivers and it worked perfectly. It missed that obvious step.